# Почему текст не с новой строки?

Tags: html, css

Вот [пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyoa6enn/15/). Что нет так?

```
#.note_box{
   padding: 3px;
   border: 1px dotted #ffc539;
   background-color: #ffdbdf;
   margin-top: 3px;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что, то что вы все записи поставили в новую строку в коде ничего не значит. Он всё равно воспринимается, как одна строчка. [Вот один из вариантов исправления](https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/Lyoa6enn/18/)

```css
.note_box{
 padding: 3px;
 border: 1px dotted #ffc539;
 background-color: #ffdbdf;
 margin-top: 3px;
 float: left;
  width: 100px;
 text-align: left;
}
span {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="note_box">
<span>22.12.2016 15:42 Загружен реестр ИМ</span>
<span>23.12.2016 17:00 Передано на сортировку</span>  
<span>24.12.2016 02:16 Принято к доставке</span>
<span>24.12.2016 07:12 Отправлено в город назначения</span>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, 2 часа мучался )

Answer (score 3):

1. Все в одну строку.
2. Ошибка в стилях `#.note_box` - нужно убрать решетку.
3. Для переноса строк можно использовать тег `br` - *устанавливает перевод строки в том месте, где этот тег находится*.

```css
.note_box{
 padding: 3px;
 border: 1px dotted #ffc539;
 background-color: #ffdbdf;
 margin-top: 3px;
 float: left;
    width: 100px;
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="note_box">
22.12.2016 15:42 Загружен реестр ИМ  <br>
23.12.2016 17:00 Передано на сортировку  <br>
24.12.2016 02:16 Принято к доставке  <br>
24.12.2016 07:12 Отправлено в город назначения  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, со <span> решил проблему